# Who sloppily brought plans to a glider later found by the Germans?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-bridge-too-far

In [1:03:26/2:56:12](https://youtu.be/H21zi9hj9-A?t=3806) of *A Bridge Too Far* (1977), a German soldier chances on a copy of operation plans. Who irresponsibly brought them on the glider?

[Captured Market Garden battleplan - Axis History Forum](https://forum.axishistory.com/viewtopic.php?t=101697)

> In the book entitled: "September Hope, The American Side of a Bridge Too Far" by John C. McManus (no relation to me), on page 151 he states:
>
> "
>
> > Only a few hours earlier, a Horsa glider from General Browning's I Airborne Corps headquarters had crash-landed in Student's area. His soldier had overrun the glider, killed one of the Allied soldiers inside, and captured ten others. In searching the craft, the German soldiers had found a copy of the 101st Airborne Division's operational plan and sent it immediately to General Student. Contrary to popular myth, this document pertained only to the 101st Airborne area of operations. It was not some sort of magical Market Garden grand plan, yet it hardly needed to be. The 101st Airborne plans, in tandem with the landings around Nijmegen and Arnhem, alerted any German commander with even a lick of sense to the fact that the Allies intended to capture the bridges and smash over the Rhine into Germany. . . .

Answer (score 5):

The plans were in that glider because the entire headquarters of [Lieutenant General Browning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Browning#Operation_Market_Garden), tactical commander (ie *feet-on-the-ground-commander*) for [Operation Market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Market_Garden#Market) (the airborne portion of [*Market Garden*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Market_Garden)), was landing with the operation: **that being the whole purpose of an operation's *tactical commander***.

Do you somehow imagine that Browning and his headquarters, no matter how well versed, had memorized the fine details of an operation involving nearly 42,000 men and developed in only 7 days from Sept. 10 to Sept. 17?